# insert into related tables in same time

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008, insert

I'm working on vb.net project. I'm using VS2010 and SQL Server 2008.

I have many tables in my database, amongst them `members` and `bank`.

- `members` contains columns: `id_member, name, mobile, tel`
- `bank` contains `id_bank, name_bank`

Then I created `member_bank` table with 2 columns: `members.id` and `bank_id` for the m:n relationship between those two tables.

How can I insert details into `members` and join member id directly with bank id in the `member_bank` table ?

I wrote this code put it doesn't work:

```
Dim saveok As Boolean = wnclass14.SQLExicute("Insert Into members (member_name,member_id,mobile,tel) values ('" & TextstdntName.Text & "','" & Textid.Text & "','" & TextMobile.Text & "','" & Texttel.Text & "')")
If saveok = True Then
        Dim saveok1 As Boolean = wnclass14.SQLExicute("Insert Into member_bank (id_member,id_bank) values (" & ComboBoxBank.SelectedValue & ")   where member_bank.id_member=members.id")

        If saveok1 = True Then .......
```

Comment: I don't know what `wnclass14` is, but either they've misspelled `Execute` or this isn't your actual code. And what do you mean by "doesn't work" - error messages? No effect whatsoever?

Comment: Arrrrrgh! That code is vulnerable to sql injection. You **cannot** use string concatenation to include data entered into user textboxes in the your sql command strings like that. It's awful. What if I entered the text `';DROP Table members;--` into the student name field? Think about what would happen. Or maybe back up your database first and try it for yourself. Then go and learn about parameterized queries.

Answer (score 2):

Part of the trick here is that you kind of want all of these to take place as part of a single transaction. Thankfully, it's not that hard to do this by sending multiple statements in a single call to your "SQLExicute" function (fix your spelling please):

```
wnclass14.SQLExicute( _
    "BEGIN TRANSACTION;" & _
    "DECLARE @NewID Int;" & _
    "INSERT INTO members (member_name, mobile, tel) " & _
      " VALUES ('..', '555-1234', '555-5678');" & _
    "SELECT @NewID = Scope_Identity();" & _ 
    "INSERT INTO member_bank (id_member, id_bank) " & _
      " VALUES (@NewID, '1234');" & _
    "COMMIT;)
```

And while we're here, you **really** need to fix this function so that it's also asking for parameter data.

It is **not** okay to to use string concatenation to include user-entered data in your sql statements.
It is **not** okay to skip this because you're still learning. And
it is **not** okay to "just get it working" first and then go back and fix the security issues afterwards

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to return the memberid from the members table after you do an insert?  If so, you need to look into `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`.  This should return the last Identity that was inserted into the table for your scope.

Here is a good article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx

I'd supply code, but I don't really understand yours.

Good luck.